# Next js 14 - How to use i18n

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js14

I am starting a project from scratch with next js 14, using /app as the directory and not using src and I have a problem when trying to use i18n according to the vercel guide

Following this guide

https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/pages-router

I have configured the middleware, the translation file and other files.

I am creating a page to log in, this component makes a fetch call to an API and logs in the user...

I have the problem trying to make the texts on this page automatically translatable according to the language

```
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */
'use client';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '@/layout/context/authcontext';
import {useTranslations} from 'next-intl';

const LoginPage = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    const { layoutConfig } = useContext(LayoutContext);

    const { login, error } = useAuth();
    const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState('');

    const handleLogin = async () => {
    ...
    ...
    };

    const router = useRouter();
    const t = useTranslations('Index');

    return (
        <div>
             <h1>{t('title')}</h1>;                
        </div>
    );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

The error I'm getting is this and it has me a little confused

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Failed to call `useTranslations` because the context from `NextIntlClientProvider` was not found.

This can happen because:
1) You intended to render this component as a Server Component, the render
   failed, and therefore React attempted to render the component on the client
   instead. If this is the case, check the console for server errors.
2) You intended to render this component on the client side, but no context was found.
   Learn more about this error here: https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/environments/server-client-components#missing-context
```

I have read next js documentation, I have consulted specialized forums and I have struggled for many hours with the component... without any success.

Comment: You say you are using the app router of Next.js, but you provided the setup for the pages router as link.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I didn't understand your contribution. Sorry, I'm a newbie user in next js.

Comment: The guide you are following, is for the pages router, isn't it?

Comment: Do you want to tell me that I should look at this guide then?


https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router

Comment: Yes, this is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inclined to use the [i18next lib](https://www.i18next.com/), the creators of the lib made a well made tutorial to help you set up internationalization with Next.js 13/14.

You can find the guide [here](https://locize.com/blog/next-app-dir-i18n/).

Additionally, they've provided a [public repository on GitHub](https://github.com/i18next/next-app-dir-i18next-example) showcasing a complete example.

Note that the **i18next** lib is more popular than **next-intl**.

Comment: I don't need the same site in /en and /es. What I want is a language switch but that only contains one page or layout. That is to say, I don't need the [lang] level that they do in the tutorials.

Comment: They explain how to do a language switch in the tutorial: https://locize.com/blog/next-app-dir-i18n/#step-4